# asp .net 4.0 membership with facebook login

Tags: asp.net, facebook

we are going to develop web-application in asp .net 4.0. in this, we are using asp .net membership provider to login the application. we want to integrate facebook login with this application. user can login to this application using facebook credential and it will be authenticated in our application. Application will allow user to invite facebook friends from this web-site.

Please suggest me on this! is there any facebook API available for this or any other way.. ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this library to fully integrate your ASP.NET application with Facebook:

[Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

some articles to start with:

[Getting Started With Facebook C# SDK](http://weblogs.asp.net/kon/archive/2010/11/15/getting-started-with-facebook-c-sdk.aspx)

[How to Retrieve User Data from Facebook Connect in ASP.NET](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-connect-in-aspnet/)

http://codesamplez.com/development/c-sharp-library-for-facebook-api

there is also another library called "Facebook Graph Toolkit", but I didn't use it before.

http://fgt.codeplex.com/